# Is watching variables in a directive the only way to trigger it at right time?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

You may have seen that pattern in most angularjs directives:

```
return {
 restrict: 'E',
 scope: {
   val: '='
 },
 link: function($scope) {
  $scope.$watch('val', function() {
    // all the code here...
  });
 }
};
```

I'm just fed up of that pattern, and was looking for something more elegant that than,
as $watching variables in each and every directives can begin to be a little bit expensive ...

The purpose of that question is how to get a directive link function code executed at the right time? In other words, when directive variables are ready.

Anyone with a better solution ?

Comment: What does "when directive variables are ready" mean?

Comment: I'm talking about the variable defined in the isolated scope of the directive, and that are absolutely necessary for the link function.

Comment: Personally I try to avoid $watch wherever possible. Instead I use ngClick/ngChange and similar to trigger some kind of handler.

Comment: Hi Yoshi can you give us a bit of example on what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen for a specific event, you could use $broadcast to broadcast a specific event and then listen for it via $on.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: to my mind this way is the worst way to go ... Events based architecture is reliable only if you have fine control on all events. Testing, maintaining code, monitoring is almost impossible if you architecture is not thought from start to rely on event. That makes a lot of if :)

Comment: To be fair I very rarely use $broadcast and usually avoid it, but it just seemed like an alternative to your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what do you mean by

> variables are ready

But one of the options is use `ng-blur` directive please see example below.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('someDirective', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: 'true',
    scope: {
      val: '='
    },
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="val" ng-blur="update()">',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.update = function() {
        alert(scope.val);
      };
    }
  };

});

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = {
    val: "test"
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="fCtrl">
    <some-directive val="data.val"></some-directive>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @sss, thanks for your answer.
By "variable are ready" I meant that variables value can come from multiple sources such as services, inputs (like in your example), resources ...etc. 
Most of that sources are asynchronous, so the problem is how to trigger the link function without a $watch but with the certitude that the variable has been set. So I was finally more "globally" than that specific use case. Thanks anyway.